# GXT 3 adding components to tabs layout is completely broken

Tags: layout, tabs, gxt

I'm building a survey creating application. The user can choose the languages they want and when they get to the 'Add Questions' screen, the languages appear on separate tabs. I have it so the questions are added to each tab, using Portlets, one for each language, and they can also add/remove options, which are TextBoxes.

The problem I'm having is that when I add a question, or add an option to the first tab and want that to propagate to the other tabs, the layout of the Portlets on the other tabs is completely broken. It's fine on the tab I'm currently on, but it doesn't seem to run any kind of layout on the other tabs because they're not in view.

I've tried calling forceLayout()on the Portlets but that doesn't do anything. What is the correct way of updating the Portlets so that the layout is as it should be?

I notice that the first time I click through the tabs it lays everything out, but doesn't do the same for any subsequent views of those tabs. Is this something I can hook into to call layout when a tab is selected?

Any ideas will help at this point.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding which gxt your trying to use like com.sencha or com.extjs.

Comment: Definitely GXT 3: com.sencha

Comment: There also version compatible between gxt-3.0.1 and gxt-3.1.0.jar file. If your trying to upgrade from old version to higher version, do verify once. This is what I guess, I am not sure.